# Print string in different lines

Tags: python

I almost have it! This code ask your for your name, age and ask if you want more copies. If "yes", it ask how many. I'm looking that the code prints the string in different lines, not a single one. I tried to use a loop but didn't figure out how to structure it. Thanks for your time.

```
def mynameandage():

    name = (input(" Hey, What's your name?"))
    age = int(input(" and how old are you?"))
    hundred = ((100-age)+2019)
    copias1=(input("Would you like more copies of this info?"))
    displaytext= (f'{name} you will be 100 years old in the year {hundred}.   ')
    if copias1 =='yes':
        cuantas= int(input("how many?"))
        return (f"  {displaytext} " *cuantas)
    else:
        return (f'Okay but remember that {displaytext}')

mynameandage()
```

Comment: what string do you mean by "the string"? Probably you're looking for the newline character (\n)

Comment: It possibly looks like you need to add \n to the end of your return statements. \n is a new line character, which makes any following text appear on the next line down. If you add this to the end of your return statements you should find that the following set of text is one line down.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to add `\n` to the end of `{displaytext}`:

```
def mynameandage():

    name = (input(" Hey, What's your name?"))
    age = int(input(" and how old are you?"))
    hundred = ((100-age)+2019)
    copias1=(input("Would you like more copies of this info?"))
    displaytext= (f'{name} you will be 100 years old in the year {hundred}.   ')
    if copias1 =='yes':
        cuantas= int(input("how many?"))
        return (f"  {displaytext}\n" * cuantas)
    else:
        return (f'Okay but remember that {displaytext}')

mynameandage()
```